# Use multiple checkboxes to change one field - rails controller change params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got articles that can be shown in lots of different sites.  They can either be visible or not.

I've ended up going for a single bitmasked permission field in the article, rather than lots of has_many permissions separate records.

I'm not sure how best to set this field.  What I've done so far is write two methods in the article model - one gives you a hash of `{1 => 'true', 2 => 'true', 3 => 'false'}` - visible or not on site `1, 2, 3`.  The second method takes a similar hash and sets the permission field correctly.

I can send the permission hash to my view through the controller, and I can make checkboxes that show if the article is visible or not.  These appear on a pop up dialog using jquery.  I haven't done it yet, but I think I can use javascript to make a hash to send back.

But I don't know how to make the update controller take the hash from the params, send it to my make permission method and then put that into the params again to update my article.

How would I go about doing this?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a `Site` model which reproduces the different sites. This is especially a good thing if there might come up more websites! Then you could build a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between the `Site` and the `Article` model to commit on which site an article should be displayed!

Comment: I've ended up doing almost what you suggested - articles already belong to sites, but I've added a ArticleSiteVisibility model for my permissions.